# Property $E[\mathbf{xx}^T] = \mathbf{\Sigma}-\mathbf{\mu\mu}^T$.

Tags: probability-distributions, gaussian

I'm reading through Principles of Machine Learning by Murphy for the purpose of understanding Gaussian Processes. For now I just want to understand the multivariate Gaussian distribution but I'm having some issues. For some $N$ dimensional random vector $\mathbf{x}$, they define the covariance matrix to be
$$
\mathbf{\Sigma} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
V[X_1] & Cov[X_1,X_2] & \dots & Cov[X_1,X_N] \\
Cov[X_2,X_1] & V[X_2] & & \\
\vdots & & \ddots & \\
Cov[X_N,X_1] & \dots & & V[X_N]
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
This is fair. But they write that $E[\mathbf{xx}^T] = \mathbf{\Sigma}-\mathbf{\mu\mu}^T$. In my mind, $\mathbf{xx}^T$ is just going to be a scalar because you have an $N\times 1$ dimensional vector multiplied by a $1 \times N$ dimensional one. But what sense does this make? The covariance matrix isn't a scalar? What am I missing here?

Comment: It is very common in statistics to write random vectors in boldfont but lowercase letter, random matrices as uppercase. So $\mathbf{x}$ will be a random vector.

Comment: Ah, your question is why a $N \times 1$ matrix multiplid by a $1 \times N$ matrix gives an $N \times N$ matrix. The answer is "just because that is what happens." You may need to go read some linear algebra first.

Comment: I still don't understand, doesn't this still mean the vector product $\mathbf{xx}^T$ is some scalar? Maybe I'm just being dumb but what does it mean to subtract a scalar from a matrix?@WilliamM.

Comment: $\bf{xx^T}$ will be an $N \times N$ matrix; $\bf{x^Tx}$ is a scalar

Comment: Oh of course I switched the order in my mind! Sorry! @layabout

Comment: Is the convention for statistics generally that $\mathbf{x}$ is a row vector or column vector? @WilliamM. I know it won't matter once you define the other but generally speaking I guess?

Comment: That is a great question, but as far as I know, "vectors" are usually "column vector" unless stated otherwise. Not only in statistics but throughout. However, in the early 20th century (i.e. 1900-1950 around), authors would choose one or the other. For example, Feller's book on Probability (An Introduction to Probability and Its Application, vol 2) uses "row vectors" as the standard! Essentially, everything is transposed.

Comment: @Ok cool to know thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answered yourself. $X$ is $N\times 1$ dimensional. Then $X^T$ is $1\times N$ dimensional. From which $XX^T$ will be $N\times N$ dimensional, a square matrix of dimension $N$.

The scalar product is $X^TX$.